# Does running mysqldump modify the binary logs?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I've read the answers to similar questions, but I don't think they answer my specific question, sorry if I am repeating here.

I am setting up replication with existing data between a master and a slave, both MyISAM. I have a master database that gets written to during the day but not overnight (ie, not now). As explained on the dev.mysql.com site, I first ran FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK on the master and obtained the binary log position using SHOW MASTER STATUS.

In another session, I then ran mysqldump on the master in order to copy this data to the slave. I ran mysqldump with the --lock-all-tables option.

However, after running mysqldump, I checked the master status again and the binary log position had increased by about 30. It has not moved up since the mysqldump finished.

Is this increase due to the mysqldump? Or did the lock not take affect and I need to re-dumo the master data?

Again, apologies if I'm repeating a question! Thanks.

Comment: This seems like an elaborate manual process. Why not just use [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)?

Comment: Thanks Asaph, my intention is to do just that, my steps have been based on the link you provide. I followed the link to Section 15.1.1 "How to setup replication" and specifically in my question I am attempting to do 15.1.1.5 "Creating a data snapshot using mysqldump".

Comment: Just to sort of close this question: Once you have taken a snapshot of the data and the master coordinates at the time of the snapshot, you can let clients start writing to the master again, while you copy the data into the slave.  You don't have to disable writing to the master the whole time until you START SLAVE.  The coordinates (master binlog file and pos) tell the slave exactly where to start replicating -- even if the master has progressed far beyond that point (as long as you don't delete the binlogs).

Answer (score 1):

Mysqldump should not cause the binary log position to change.

You need to investigate why it changed. Look inside the binary logs to get an idea of what was written to it. Use [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) command for this.

For example if you recorded the initial position as 1234 in binlog.0000003, then execute:

```
mysqlbinlog --start-position=1234 binlog.0000003
```

This should show you the changes that were applied after certain position in a binary log.